# XPath - How to access anchor text and href from the current node in a loop

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I am using Scrapy along with XPath. In a scenario, i need to get the anchor element's href and text.

What i did is:

1. Get all the anchor from the container using a selector
2. Looped through the anchors to find href and text. I am able to get the href but not text.

Here is the snippet to understand better

```
anchors = response.selector.xpath("//table[@class='style1']//ul//li//a")
for anchor in anchors:
    link = anchor.xpath('@href').extract()[0]
    name = anchor.xpath('[how-to-access-current-node-here]').text()
```

How can i achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not really great at understanding terms, by **anchor** you mean the **text** for **a** right? You can simply use **text()**

Comment: ah I see, anchor is the one with like `.../...#blah blah`. I have given an answer and hope it's what you're after

Comment: Can you please show your HTML input? Otherwise, it's impossible to give a useful answer.

Comment: scrapy also provides shortcuts `response.xpath` and `response.css` so `response.selector` isnt really needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use xpath **text()**, provided that you know where the header text is (from **a**), let's say from your sample if the header text is within **a**'s parent **element**, then extracting it is only go a level back, like this:

```
anchors = response.selector.xpath("//table[@class='style1']//ul//li//a")
for anchor in anchors:
    link = anchor.xpath('@href').extract()[0]
    # go one level back and access text()
    name = anchor.xpath('../text()').extract()
```

Or, better still you do even need to do this under a for loop, just use **extract** and it will return a list:

```
anchors = response.selector.xpath("//table[@class='style1']//ul//li//a")

links = anchors.xpath('@href').extract()
names = anchors.xpath('../text()').extract()

paired_links_with_names = zip(links, names)
...
# you may do your thing here or still do a for / loop
```

Of course you need to inspect the elements and find out where the header text is of course, it's only how you access that text from your existing xpath location.

Hope this helps.